# Flood fill GLUT code not working

Tags: c++, opengl, recursion, glut, flood-fill

I wrote the following piece of code for flood-fill as part of a paint program I'm developing:

```
void setPixel(int x, int y)
{
     glColor4f(red, green, blue, alpha);
     glBegin(GL_POINTS);
     glVertex2f(x, y);
     glEnd();
     glFlush();
}
void floodFill(int x, int y)
{
     unsigned char pick_col[3];
     float R, G, B;
     glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pick_col);
     R = (float) pick_col[0]/255.0;
     G = (float) pick_col[1]/255.0;
     B = (float) pick_col[2]/255.0;

     //std::cout<<R<<" "<<G<<" "<<B<<"\n";

     if(R!=0.0 || G!=0.0 || B!=0.0) //true for any non-black colour (BTW, my canvas is black)
     return;

     setPixel(x,y);

     floodFill(x+1,y);
     floodFill(x,y+1);
     floodFill(x,y-1);
     floodFill(x-1,y);
}
```

Unfortunately, this code is not working. For example, I first drew a rectangle and tried to fill the rectangle. What actually happened was that from the point where I clicked to fill, pixels to its right started getting filled in a line and eventually the pixels near the right-most edge started getting drawn. But that's all that happened. I don't understand why.

Comment: Why are you converting the RGB values to `float`? Why not just check for zero and be done with it?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Okay, so I modified the code to avoid the conversion but the code still doesn't work. I have the feeling my algorithm is incorrect but it doesn't seem so when I look at the code.

Comment: Try reading from this website... https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

First of all: don't do this. Doing it completely on the CPU will be *orders of magnitude* faster than doing 2 roundtrips to the GPU *per pixel*.

Having said that, I can still see the problem with your implementation: you are never checking the borders. `glReadPixels` will just return *undefined* results if you try to read back pixels which lie outside of the framebuffer, and that might very well be all zeros.